# Finding value of a complex integral with residues by intuition

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have $f(z)=z^3-1$.  Clearly there the three complex roots of unity,

$$1, -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
 and so for simplifity I will just denote these as $1, \omega, $ and $\omega^2$.

If I need to find,

$$\oint_C\frac{dz}{f(z)}$$ on the closed curve defined as $C: |z|=2$, and I could use the residue theorem.  However, if I expand $f$ out in a Laurent series, it would be the case that the coefficients of $f$ are nonzero ONLY at those powers that are multiples of $3$, and therefore, wouldn't the result of the integral simply be $0$ since $a_{-1}$, the coefficient of $f$ in the Laurent series expansion is zero?

Then is this true for all complex functions $f$ of the form $z^k-1$?

Comment: Easier maybe, more generally applicable: By Cauchy's integral theorem, the integral doesn't depend on the radius of the circle as long as it's larger than $1$. Now if you take a really large radius …

Comment: Right, but the simple poles are inside the path, so doesn't that need residue?  If $f(x)=1/((z-1)(z-\omega))$ the residues would not sum to $0$, right?

Comment: They would: $$\frac{1}{(z-a)(z-b)} = \frac{1}{a-b}\biggl(\frac{1}{z-a} - \frac{1}{z-b}\biggr).$$

Comment: Ah...  The residue for each function is $2\pi i$ so their difference is 0.  Okay.  I see.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, for an integer $k > 0$ we have the Laurent expansion

$$\frac{1}{z^k-1} = z^{-k}\frac{1}{1-z^{-k}} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} z^{-nk}$$

for $\lvert z\rvert > 1$, and for $k > 1$ in this Laurent series the power $z^{-1}$ has coefficient $0$, so

$$\int_{\lvert z\rvert = R} \frac{dz}{z^k-1} = 0$$

for $R > 1$ and $k > 1$.

The sum of the residues at the simple poles $\zeta_m = \exp \frac{2\pi i m}{k},\; 0 \leqslant m < k$ is $0$, and the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion valid for $\lvert z\rvert > 1$ is the sum of all residues in the closed unit disk.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you for your help!